# Listing subpages in categories on mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I'm using [subpages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aSubpages) to group product functionality. Unfortunately all subpages participating in a [category](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aCategory) are displayed with their parent page making the alphabetic separation significantly less useful.

Is there a way to list the subpages differently in the category? In particular, if only subpages participate in the category, just stripping out the parent would make the category page much more friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just set the [sort key](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aCategories#Sort_key), possibly using a template (or a module) that figures out the correct sort key based on the page title.

Comment: Thank you for your reply; it's certainly a step in the right direction but I'd still prefer to not have the parent/base page name reflecting in the category listing. If I can't find any alternatives, I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be... don't use sub pages.

When you use subpages, you're bunging in an extra prefix as part of your wiki pages titles. There's quite a few disadvantages to cluttering up your wiki page titles in this way. You're hitting one disadvantage, that wiki page titles are generally displayed in full. Another big one is that wiki page titles are the mechanism by which you link to a page, so now users (who may be learning how to wiki link for the first time) have to bung in more cruft into their [[links]].

Subpages are tempting in their very up-front way of establishing some hierarchical order, but wikis more naturally take a flat structure. A web of interlinked pages (which may have a hierarchical link structure) rather than a fixed hierarchy forced within the wiki page names.