# Reverse sort of pages in MediaWiki category listing

Tags: mediawiki

In MediaWiki, I want a gallery of images from a certain category, sorted by most recent first.  (I am hoping to use MediaWiki core instead of relying on extensions.)

I tagged images with `Category:Art` so can now display a "gallery" of the images with the category listing.

I still want to sort the images in this category by most recent first.

Per [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57513/20025):
I tried using the date as [sort key](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories#Sort_key) for the images in my category, but the images are still [in order by oldest first](https://wiki.robnugen.com/wiki/Category:Art).

One solution would be to reverse the sort order of the category listing.

I see [$wgCategoryCollation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCategoryCollation#Numeric_sorting), but even with Numeric sorting, it cannot sort things in reverse.

Another option would be to filter by category the [`Gallery of New Files`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:New_files) but there is apparently no built-in way to do that.

Is there a built-in way to show a filtered set of images, most recent first?

Comment: Do you want to change how the category page looks, or just get that information somehow? In the latter case, just use [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers).

Comment: I want to change how the Category page looks.

Comment: You can define a custom collation via the `Collation::factory` hook, but it's a lot simpler to just use inverse timestamps as sort keys in the first place (e.g. Unix epoch but with the real upload date mirrored around 2000, so `2 * 946684800 - $unixTime`). It's a horrible hack though.